# Converting strings into int when importing .txt files

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm following this tutorial from Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyhqzaMiFxk&index=7&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfefDfXb9Yf0la1fPDKluPF.

The purpose is to import a .txt file into Phyton and use its data to plot a graph in matplotlib. One thing to do before that is to convert the strings into integers/floats.

Below is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('ages.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(int(row[0]))
        y.append(int(row[1]))
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

However, I can't get the result in the video. Below is the error message:

```
    x.append(int(row[0]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\cocoartf1504\\cocoasubrtf830'
```

My .txt file is as follows

```
1,56
2,27
3,65
4,44
5,38
6,97
7,56
8,35
9,64
10,12
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: To me it looks like csv.reader extracts more than just the two data colums you expect. What does `print(plots)` return? The error basically tells you that row[0] cannot be converted to integer. Which makes sense when row[0] is "{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\cocoartf1504\\cocoasubrtf830'". Does the data have a header?

Comment: "Is there something wrong with my code?" It's more likely that the content of the file is not what you think it is

Comment: You saved your "txt file" as an RTF file instead. That is a way more complicated file type than plain text.

Answer (score 1):

If you save your text file as a flat text file(plain text), instead of RTF, your code works fine.

RTF files include extra data for text layout and format, which is causing your code to pick up extra metadata while reading each line.

There are libraries which support text extraction of RTF files, such as [textract](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract), but it's probably just easier to save the text file as plain text to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If you save your file as plain text, your code seems to work. However you can do something simpler:

```
values = np.loadtxt('ages.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=int)
plt.plot(*values.T)
```